# JPA Criteria API .in-Clause with empty list

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I use JPA Criteria API to create a query:

```
    List<Area> areas = areaService.getAreasForUser(user);
    Join<Equipment, Area> areaJoin = equipment.join(Equipment_.area);
    wheres.add(areaJoin.get(Area_.id).in(areas));
```

Which means I want to get all `Area`s where a `User` has access.

In a `User` has `Area`s it will evaluate to `... where area.id IN (1, 2, 3)` which works fine.

When a `User` has no `Area`s it evaluates to: `... where area.id IN ()` which will result as error.

Can you give me a tip how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, this is invalid SQL (never understood why). So you need to avoi generating and executing the query in the first place if the list is empty and, usually, just return an empty list directly from your method instead.

Comment: A JPA provider ought to be able to cope with empty list for IN, and equate to (1=0). Which JPA provider?

Comment: See this issue https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-100